# Unity 2D - Stop looping animation smoothly

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

So, I have a screen that displays an animation that covers the whole screen.

Now, I have 7 looping animations, all starting and ending at the same frame for compatibility. But how can I make it that after a button press I can wait for each animation to finish before the next is played so it looks smooth?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: No sorry, there is no code here yet as I have not figured out a good way. Animation Events seem nice, but also kinda overkill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you'll need to sort out is an animator controller. This animator controller is aware of all the necessary animations that can be played. You don't have to connect things up if you don't want to, as it stands 7 animations that can be played in any order... That's a lot of links.

In order to get it working, your animator controller would need bool parameters that represent each transition, so when you set them from script, the controller will move in the direction it is supposed to. To make a transition occur, when the clip reaches the end, set the transition exit time to be 1. Bare in mind, you'll still need to manage a front end queue data structure and reset bools when the transition begins, this'll prevent it from reaching the next state and immediately transitioning to another one.

Instead, you can write a custom handler for this which will set the currently playing animation. Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
class YourAnimController : MonoBehaviour
{
       private Queue<int> queuedStateHashes = new Queue<int>();

       private int currentStateHash;

       public string defaultState;
       private int defaultHash;

       public Animator theAnimator;

       private void Awake()
       {
           defaultHash = Animator.StringToHash(defaultState);
           StartCoroutine(PlayStates());
       }

       //how you start and exit this is up to you, in this case, 
       //I'll assume it starts on awake
       private IEnumerator PlayStates()
       {
            while(true)
            {          
                SetAnimStates();

                yield return null;
            }                              
       }

       private void SetAnimState()
       {
           AnimatorStateInfo info = theAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);

           if(queuedStates.Count > 0)
           {
               if(info.normalizedTime >= 1)
               {
                   currentStateHash = queuedStateHashes.Dequeue();

                   theAnimator.Play(currentStateHash, 0, 0);                                                                       
               }
           }               
           else if(currentStateHash != defaultStateHash)
           {
               queuedStateHashes.Enqueue(defaultStateHash);                  
           }                     
       }

       private void Update()
       {
            if(Input.GetButtonDown("Your button1"))
            {
                 int stateHash = Animator.StringToHash("First state");
                 queuedStateHashes.Enqueue(stateHash);                                         
            }
            //repeat for all additional anims
       }

       //Any other methods
}
```

Now for an explanation:
The queue is used to queue up the states to play, this allows them to be played in a particular order, first come first serve.

The PlayStates method logic could be transposed over to the Update method. You'd be doing it after the input checks, and you'd remove the while loop. I did it this way as it can give you more control over when and how it stops and starts, whereas the update will be constantly evaluated. This approach allows you to shut the coroutine down if you don't have any states in the queue, should you choose to do this. There's a challenge for you :). Don't forget to start it back up when you hit a button.

The animator state info grab tells us what is currently playing inside the animator controller. The normalised time is used because you need to know how far the animation has progressed. The normalised time is basically the percentage of the current animation that has been played. Provided looping isn't on for the animation clip, in which case it tells you the percentage and how many times it has played. Debug and see for yourself, if you're curious.

This approach will need to be modified to take looping into account, so it will only change the animation after the animation has completed it's cycle. You may need to modify this bit:

```
if(info.normalizedTime >= 1 && queuedStates.Count > 0)
```

to get it working, another challenge :).

Now for some documents:

AnimatorStateInfo:  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo.html

Queue: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx

Animator: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html

The animator controller approach, with links all over the place, uses a similar idea, it may be trickier to implement, and more time consuming when you setup the controller, whereas the approach outlined above, shouldn't require transitions, if the documentation is to be believed:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.Director.IAnimatorControllerPlayable.html

Hopefully this'll lead you in the right direction.

Comment: It seems this challenge is a little bit too hard for me. It perfectly works, yet I get a memory overflow: CODE: http://pastebin.com/bm3dqSHm    

PROFILER: http://imgur.com/a/dB2pl   

The spike happened after I pressed a button and ended after the animation finished. The animations are all not looping, that's what line 43 should be for. Would it be uncommented, the memory usage would go up until an overflow happens. What exactly is happening in the background here?

Comment: Update, this behaviour seems to even be apparent when I am simply starting the states with Play() without queuing. Once the textures get read, the memory is not freed again and even if I start the same state again, it just reads it again and allocates double the memory.

Comment: Not sure what the problem. I ran the code and tested it, it works fine. It doesn't handle the looping behaviour correctly, a challenge for you, but the code is fine and doesn't generate garbage. Check that you're not recording while play mode is on, may be causing the issue. Another thing, to loop an animation you need to check 'Loop Time' on the actual animation file.

Comment: Just realized that if statement is wrong, the one in SetAnimState method. Fixed it now. Your own implementation removed that error. Nicely done.

Comment: My issue was that I did not compress the frames correctly, so they took more than 4 GB, more than my RAM-space. After compression it is down to about 100MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can add each animations script a custom variable.These variables should match exactly the order you want.When each animation ends,assign a custom value to that variable and start next animations script based on that variables value that you just assigned.

Comment: The order is dynamic (as in, if you push the "smooth transition to 3" button, it will wait until the end of the current animation and then start the animation 3), so could you explain a little bit more detailed please? I am not sure if this would be efficient with the "control panel" of buttons I have on the screen, since every button would need to be able to access the variables of every single animation and not just a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Let try Animator.speed :
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-speed.html

You can try [Mathf.Lerf](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html)(1f, 0f, 0.5f) but i think it may be complex to handle. :D